# Powershell Get-WMIObject fails with “Invalid class” error

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, vlan, wmi

Trying to get VLAN Id for VMs in Hyper-V
The following commands throws "invalid class" error when run from power shell:

Get-WmiObject -Class Msvm_VLANEndpointSettingData -Namespace "root\virtualization" -ComputerName "."

What is the right namespace to be used?

Comment: Your namespace appears correct: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136947(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

root\virtualization has been removed in recent versions of Hyper-V.  You want root\virtualization\v2.

Comment: Have tried "root\virtualization\v2" too, the same issues persists.

Comment: Yes.  The entire namespace has been deprecated.  You need to find the corresponding class in the root\virtualization\v2 namespace, and perhaps a slightly different approach.  Read the documentation.